# Don't reload the popup in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension and every time the user click on the icon the popup.html page is loaded(reloaded). Is there a way to load the popup page only the first time, or to load it in the background?

Here is the code from my background script

```
var x=false;
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    if(x==false){
        alert("test");
        chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: "popup.html"});
    }
});
```

So the *alert("text")* is triggered only one time, but the popup.html is changed every time I click the icon. In popup.html I simply generate a different random number.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=Math.random();
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everytime a users clicks the browserAction button chrome will open or close the attached popup. There is no way to stop it.